# IPython Jupyter: uploading folder

Tags: ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

Can you upload entire folders in IPython Jupyter? If so, how? I know how to upload individual files, of course, but this can get tedious if there are a large number of files and/or subdirectories.

Comment: You could upload a zip file, then start a notebook and use the [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) module from Python to extract it.

Comment: I opened an issue to track this https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3747

Comment: You should mark the answer from Joys as the answer.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Convert it into a single Zip file and upload that.
to unzip the folder use the code down bellow

```
import zipfile as zf
files = zf.ZipFile("ZippedFolder.zip", 'r')
files.extractall('directory to extract')
files.close()
```

However, sometimes you may need to download several files from notebook. There are several ways to do this but the easiest way is to zip a directory and download the zip file:

```
import shutil
shutil.make_archive(output_filename_dont_add_.zip, 'zip', directory_to_download)
```

Answer (score 14):

Maybe it is easier to just use unix to just unzip the data.

Steps:

1. Transform the folder into a .zip file in your computer.
2. Upload the .zip file to jupyter home.
3. In jupyter notebook run

`! unzip ~/yourfolder.zip -d ~/`

where

`!` tells the jupyter notebook that you are going to give code directly to unix, not python code

`unzip` is the unzip commmand

`~/yourfolder.zip` tells the command where your .zip folder is (at `~/` if you uploaded to the home folder)

`-d ~/` tells the command where you want to put the unzipped folder (this assumes you want to put it in the home folder, but you can also put it in any other subfolder with `-d ~/my_first_level_subfolder` or `-d ~/my_first_level_subfolder/my_second_level_subfolder`, etc.)

4. If you want to delete the original .zip folder, delete it manually at jupyter home or use

`!rm ~/yourfolder.zip`

Hope if helps somebody

Comment: Just want to mention that there is also a Terminal which can be reached via Jupyter File Explorer -> "New ▼" -> "Terminal" in order to perform the `unzip [archiv.zip] -d [dest]` command.

Answer (score 2):

Put your folder into

```
C:\Users\'YOUR USER NAME'\
```

Comment: This is a very bad answer as it ignores the possibility of having a non Windows OS, a possibility of running the code from a server, and even the possibility of using a Docker container

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, open terminal in Jupyter. You will get a Windows Powershell! Command prompt will be PS. It will show the local folder name also. But if Jupyter is remote, then do this:-
 * Open Terminal as already mentioned above
 * Create a single zipped file out of all your folders/files
 * Drag and drop the zipped file into Jupyter.. it will get uploaded
 * Open Terminal
 * Use powershell commands to upload as explained in [this powershell link](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/11/06/using-powershell-to-create-zip-archives-and-unzip-files/). It will be something like this:-

```
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath <name of zipped file> -DestinationPath .
```